# Asp.Net The network path was not found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET website with MSSQL DB connection in it. I can use the IP address, user id and password parameters what the hosting service gave me to access the database in my MSSQL server. I can access the database in MSSQL server without a problem but when I tried to add connectionstring to my `web.config` file with same parameters, it showing me this error message. I tried almost anything to fix but no luck. This is my error code and stack trace, thanks in advance.

This is my connection.cs file which im using for db queries.myDB my ID etc. are just for representation

```
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source=serverIP; Initial Catalog=myDB; User ID=myID; Password=myPass; Integrated Security=false");
            baglanti.Open();
            SqlConnection.ClearPool(baglanti);
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            return (baglanti);
```

And this is my connection string file.myDB my ID etc. are just for representation

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TstConnectionString" connectionString="Server=serverIP; Initial Catalog=myDB; User ID=myID; Password=myPass;Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />                                           
  </connectionStrings>
```

and there is the error section

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The network path was not found
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +443
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   tstSite.esqbaglantisi.baglan() +38
   TstSite.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +32
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +780

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0`
```

Comment: Please post your code in which you connect to the DB

Comment: Can you access the instance you trying to connect to with SSMS ?

Comment: your connection information is invalid in some way, and/or your SQL server is not configured to be accessed from the location where your application is hosted. Check your settings and your setup. Show your connection string here too, in case there's an obvious mistake in it

Comment: `Integrated Security=false` is meaningless. If you use a username/password, don't add that keyword

Comment: I edited the question, added my connection.cs file and  connectionstring code in web.config file.

Comment: As for the error itself, are you *sure* you can connect to that database using the IP? A DNS lookup shows that this IP belongs to TurboHost. I doubt that they expose their database servers to the public internet. Perhaps you need a VPN?

Comment: Can you make sure the sql server accepts connections from your web server on port 1433? You can test it by running Telnet command - telnet databaseip 1433

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i can connect that IP with my mssql server and import my tables that i exported from an other db of mine

Comment: @user635388 I tried to run Telnet command and after for a while, it states "press any key to continue" and when i do it states " Connection to host lost"  plus i can not ping that IP from windows command prompt